# Подгрузка данных с API+DB используя offset и limit

Tags: java, android, paging

У меня есть вот такой метод API

```
@GET("apiV2/Friend/GetAllFriendsForUser")
Observable<Response<List<Friend>>> getAllFriendsForUser(@Query("userId") String userId, @Query("take") int take, @Query("skip") int skip);
```

с помощью которого я динамически подгружаю объекты.

До того как появились аргументы skip  и take  проблем небыло, потому что я использовал  следующий класс

```
public abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType> {

    private static final String TAG = NetworkBoundResource.class.getSimpleName();

    private final MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    // Called to save the result of the API response into the database
    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract void saveCallResult(@NonNull RequestType data);

    // Called with the data in the database to decide whether it should be
    // fetched from the network.
    @MainThread
    protected abstract boolean shouldFetch(@Nullable ResultType data);

    // Called to get the cached data from the database
    @NonNull
    @MainThread
    protected abstract LiveData<ResultType> loadFromDb();

    // Called to create the API call.
    @NonNull
    @MainThread
    protected abstract LiveData<Observable<Response<RequestType>>> createCall();

    // Called when the fetch fails. The child class may want to reset components
    // like rate limiter.
    @MainThread
    protected abstract void onFetchFailed(Throwable throwable);

    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();


    @MainThread
    protected NetworkBoundResource() {
        result.setValue(Resource.loading(null));
        LiveData<ResultType> dbSource = loadFromDb();

        result.addSource(dbSource, data -> {
            result.removeSource(dbSource);

            if (shouldFetch(data)) {
                fetchFromNetwork(dbSource);
            } else {
                result.addSource(dbSource,

                        newData -> {
                            if (newData == null) {
                                NetworkBoundResource.this.result.setValue(Resource.empty());
                            } else {
                                NetworkBoundResource.this.result.setValue(Resource.success(newData));
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    private void fetchFromNetwork(final LiveData<ResultType> dbSource) {
        LiveData<Observable<Response<RequestType>>> apiResponse = createCall();
        // we re-attach dbSource as a new source,
        // it will dispatch its latest value quickly
        result.addSource(dbSource, newData -> result.setValue(Resource.loading(newData)));
        result.addSource(apiResponse, observer -> {

            result.removeSource(apiResponse);
            result.removeSource(dbSource);

            //return if observable is null
            if (observer == null) return; 

            observer
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> compositeDisposable.add(disposable))
                    .subscribe(
                            this::saveResultAndReInit,
                            throwable -> {
                                onFetchFailed(throwable);

                                //put error to result
                                result.setValue(Resource.error(throwable));

                                //put cached data to result if it exist
                                result.addSource(dbSource, newData -> {
                                    if (newData==null){
                                        result.setValue(Resource.empty());
                                    }else {
                                        result.setValue(Resource.success(newData));
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                    );
        });
    }

    @MainThread
    private void saveResultAndReInit(Response<RequestType> response) {
        new UpdateAsync(response).execute();
    }

    public final LiveData<Resource<ResultType>> getAsLiveData() {

        return result;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class UpdateAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Response<RequestType> response;

        UpdateAsync(Response<RequestType> response) {
            this.response = response;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RequestType body = response.body();
            if (body != null) NetworkBoundResource.this.saveCallResult(body);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            // we specially request a new live data,
            // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
            // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.

            //if database value is null just send empty result
            //otherwise return existing value
            LiveData<ResultType> resultTypeLiveData = loadFromDb();

            NetworkBoundResource.this.result.addSource(resultTypeLiveData,
                    newData -> {
                        if (newData == null) {
                            NetworkBoundResource.this.result.setValue(Resource.empty());
                        } else {
                            NetworkBoundResource.this.result.setValue(Resource.success(newData));
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

и использовал его следующим образом

```
public LiveData<Resource<List<MessageObjectView>>> getMessageObjectViews(String userId) {
    return new NetworkBoundResource<List<MessageObjectView>, List<MessageObjectView>>() {
        @Override
        protected void saveCallResult(@NonNull List<MessageObjectView> data) {
            dao.insertAllMessageObjectView(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean shouldFetch(@Nullable List<MessageObjectView> data) {
            return true;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected LiveData<List<MessageObjectView>> loadFromDb() {
            return dao.getAllMessageObjectViewAsLiveData();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected LiveData<Observable<Response<List<MessageObjectView>>>> createCall() {

            Observable<Response<List<MessageObjectView>>> apiResponse = api.getMessageObjectsObs(userId);
            MutableLiveData<Observable<Response<List<MessageObjectView>>>> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            liveData.setValue(apiResponse);
            return liveData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onFetchFailed(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Fetch list " + MessageObjectView.class.getName() + " failed. " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }.getAsLiveData();
}
```

Т.е. таким образом я мог всегда подтянуть актуальные данные из сети, сохранив их в базу данных и вернув в методже уже данные сохраненные в БД.

Но у меня данный способ работает когда я запрашиваю какие то конкретные данные, а когда мне нужно  добывать данные через offset, limit -  уменя возникаю проблемы.

Пробовал смотреть в сторону разлиных `DataSource` используя `Paging Library` но так не не с мог для себя найти решение как это реализовать в случае когда у меня "единственные источник данных" ?

Вопрос, как или с помощью чего можно реализовать нужную для меня схему работы (подрузка из API  с offset, limit -> сохранение данных в БД -> вернуть результат для данного запроса из БД)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то проблема в том, что при поступлении новых данных в БД вы получаете не то, что вам надо в соответствии с limit и offset, а все, что есть в БД? Если так, то я видел варианты решения через DiffUtils, что на мой взгляд приводит к неоправданному расходу ресурсов.

Сам я решал проблему через указание `limit` и `offset` (у меня это были время последнего сообщения `created` перед пополнением БД и количеством загруженных сообщений `count`), типа:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM messages " +
        "WHERE messages.conversationUuid LIKE :conversationUuid " +
        "AND messages.created < :created " +
        "ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT :count")
List<Message> loadMessages(String conversationUuid, int count, long created);
```

P.S. Вместо `LiveData` я использовал `RxJava` и адаптированный под нее класс [`NetworkBoundResource`](https://gist.github.com/anitaa1990/8b2474b2053e0a9a384b76be11d0b7b0).